# SlickGrid best Way to Up/Down Row with cell button

Tags: slickgrid

I search an issue to up/down row with buttons. 
I m trying to use 'grid.getCurrentCell' but when i click button currentCell is not yet define.

How can i do this ?

Thanks.

(sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using the ID of your row. When you create the row, set the button to
<a onclick='moveUp(23)'><img src='up.gif'></a>

Where 23 is the index in your data. You could also update this by calling:

```
for(var i in data)
  data[i]['upButtonColumn']="<a onclick='moveUp("+i+")'><img src='up.gif'></a>";
grid.removeRows(rows);
grid.render();
```

Or something similar, but that would be slower.